I need to split data that is in single single into three rows in excel
I need three different rows for each game_id , passing_quote and winner.
I expect three diferent rows along with data
All the data that is in--> Excel
IS there any formula for sam , how don we use formula or else from any drop down .PLease help.

You mean you want your data to look like this: row1=11, row2=72, row3 = No, row4=11, row5=91, row6 = Yes… ??

I'm not even going to try to follow that link. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

@CHill60, yes, also for security reasons. I am still trying to git rid of the habit of clicking random URLs.....

This should be easy using the Text To Columns from the Data Tab and split by delimiter semi-colon. Or if you are looking for a formula then use TEXTSPLIT(). You can also use Power Query.



=LET(α, TEXTSPLIT(A1,";"), IFERROR(--α,α))


Or, to do this for the whole range all at once, then:


=LET(α, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(";"&A1:A8,";",{1,2,3}),";"), IFERROR(--α,α))


Or, Use MAKEARRAY()
=LET(
     _Data, A1:A8,
     _Delim, MAX(LEN(_Data) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(_Data, ";",)) + 1),
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Data),_Delim,LAMBDA(α,δ,
     IFERROR(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(_Data,α), ";"), δ), ""))))


Or Use REDUCE() function:
=DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",A1:A8,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTSPLIT(y,";")))),""),1)


NOTE: Ensure to increase the range as per your suit

